# I need to automatically delete a row if cells on separate sheets match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that automatically deletes an entire row in sheet #1 if:

- Cells in column B on sheet #2 are an exact match of cells in column A on sheet #1.

The row I want to delete is the row with the matching cell in sheet #1.

Here is a mock sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jjvzgTPlK7pPTRyaRkXKn3Pq8NbecJonHstDs-dJgAM/edit?usp=sharing

---

I am assuming that I will probably need a time-based trigger for this to work the way I need it to, but don't know where to start.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples, showing the matches and which rows are supposed to get deleted?

Comment: Sure. Here is a mock sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jjvzgTPlK7pPTRyaRkXKn3Pq8NbecJonHstDs-dJgAM/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet #1 constantly gets updated and we end up with a lot of duplicates.

Comment: To set-up a time-based trigger, go from the Apps Script UI to `Edit > Current project's triggers->Add new one`. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteMatches() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(3,1,sh1.getLastRow()-2,1);
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(3,2,sh2.getLastRow()-2,1);//Assuming data on sheet2 starts on same row
  var vA2=rg2.getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA1.length;i++) {
    if(vA2.indexOf(vA1[i][0])!=-1) {
      sh1.deleteRow(i+3-d++)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cooper. This doesn't quite work. It is deleting ALL rows in sheet 1.

Comment: I modified the code a bit and tested it on some of my own data.  I think it will work for you know.

Comment: Cooper, perfect! Works like a dream. Thanks.